# Removing a trailing slash using htaccess for specefic route

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm adding a trailing slash at the end of the URL using `.htaccess`.
Is there a way to exclude a specific route from adding that trailing slash

What is what happens now:

```
example.com/sitemap/
```

What I want:

```
example.com/sitemap
```

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
</IfModule>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
        RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So show us your .htaccess as it currently stands

Comment: This is what i have now.
https://pastebin.com/cA5DP7ja

Comment: It is always best to paste information into the question. Off site resources have a habit of dissapearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
> ```

This would seem to be the code that is appending a trailing slash. So, you can include an additional condition to *exclude* the mentioned URL. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex. So, a pattern like `!^/sitemap$` will match any URL that is not `/sitemap`.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.